# Google Cloud SQL: Does edit instances (PostgreSQL) in part 'Connectivity' make DB downtime?

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, devops, google-cloud-sql

I have an instances PostgreSQL 11 on production of a web application.
Now, i want to modify the connectivity part to use internal IP and disable the public connection.
Do this activity make a little downtime for our DB?

I have guest on my own:

1. GCP only changes the network part of this instances so we can get zero downtime.
2. GCP will re-configure the instance host this PostgreSQL and this make a little downtime for our DB, the thing we dont want with our production.

Tks in advance!

Comment: To switch connections from Public IP to Private IP will incur downtime on the clients. The clients will need to close their current connections to reconnect. However, I don't think you can remove the Public IP without rebooting the database instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given the fact that you are using Cloud SQL for PostgreSQL, you can consider the following from the **[Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/instance-settings#impact):**

> **For most instance settings, Cloud SQL applies the change immediately and connectivity to the instance is unaffected.**

Changing the number of CPUs, memory size, or the zone of the instance results in the instance going offline for several minutes. You should plan to make these kind of changes when your application can handle an outage of this length.

---

### Update

As per the **[documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/private-ip#administration_considerations)**, besides changing the number of CPUs, memory size, and zone of the instance, **configuring an existing instance to use private IP, or changing the network it is connected to, causes the instance to be restarted**. **This causes a few minutes of downtime.**

Comment: This does not answer the question. This should be a comment attached to the question.

Comment: Thank you @JohnHanley for the comment, I already updated my answer to clarify further.

Comment: Thank you for updating to include the relevant information.